# Match a string but capture only substring of it's match in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, jekyll, rouge

I am extending `rouge` shell lexer for my `jekyll` site and I want to do the following.

1. Match `--word`. Capture `word`, discard `--`.
2. Match `<word>`. Capture `word`, discard both `<` and `>`.
3. Match `word=anyNumber.word`. Capture `word` and `anyNumber.word`, discard `=`.

First I have tried `/(?=-+)\w/`, didn't match anything, then I tried to do reverse and discard `word` such as `/-+(?=\w*)/`, and it worked. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Adding a small example and the desired result would be helpful. If you do that, be sure to assign a variable to each input value (`str = "..."`) so that readers can refer to the variables without having to define them.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're overthinking this. You don't need lookahead or lookbehind here.

```
str = "foo --word1 <word2> word3=anyNumber.word4"

p /--(\w+)/.match(str).captures
# => ["word1"]

p /<([^>]+)>/.match(str).captures
# => ["word2"]

p /(\w+)=([\w.]+)/.match(str).captures
# => ["word3", "anyNumber.word4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "--hopscotch <dodgeball> cat=9.lives"

str[/(?<=\-\-)\w+/]
  #=> "hopscotch" 
str[/(?<=\<)\w+(?=\>)/]
  #=> "dodgeball" 
str.scan /(?:\w+(?=\=))|(?<=\=)\d+\.\w+/
  #=> ["cat", "9.lives"]
```